# Re-using the already themed output of another module in a custom module

Tags: theming

I have a function in a custom module that pulls out the formatted (already themed) output of another module:

```
function custom_get_ph1() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'another_module', 'includes/another_module.pages');
  global $user;
  $list = another_module_list_page('user', $user->uid);
  return $list;
}
```

And I am trying to put its output into an unordered list of my custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */

function custom_menu() {
  $items['user/%/hobbies'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hobbies',
    'page callback' => 'custom_hobbies',
    'page arguments' => array('user', 1),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,
  );
  return $items;
}

function custom_hobbies() {
$content ='
  <ul>
    <li>placeholder1</li>
    <li>placeholder1</li>
    <li>placeholder1</li>
  </ul>'
 return $content;
}
```

How to get themed output of another module (object) into the list of my custom module (string).

Comment: If the accepted answer works, then your understanding of the problem is flawed, and likely why there was confusion. Your `custom_get_ph1()` returns a render array and not rendered output.  They are two totally different things.

Comment: My English and knowledge of terminology might not be perfect, but what is important here is that the accepted answer takes care of what I was trying to achieve. So don't be so much of grammar-nazi and use common sense - if you see what someone is asking for just try to be helpful.

Comment: People *are* trying to help you here.  "Render arrays" and "rendered output" are key Drupal concepts and two totally different things.  You may have achieved your short term goals, but may be setting yourself up for problems in the long run.  Page callbacks should return render arrays.  Theme functions call `drupal_render()` to convert render arrays into HTML fragments, which get assembled into a page.

Comment: The code for the page callback you are showing is not even using the output returned from another function. What you say (_I am trying to put its output into an unordered list of my custom module_) doesn't match what your code is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite hard to tell without knowing what `another_module_list_page()` returns, but I assume it is a render array. This can be converted to HTML by passing it through [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7.x)

So I guess you should be able to do this using [theme_item_list()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7.x):

```
function custom_hobbies() {
  // Add one render array as a child of another one.
  $items = array();
  $items[] = custom_get_ph1();

  $content = array(
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#items' => $items,
    '#type' => 'ul',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'my-list'), // optional
  );

  return $content;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, while this may work, it is best practice to return a render array from an HTML page callback and not rendered output.  A better solution would be to rework `custom_hobbies()` to do this, and inside it would would merge in the render array from `custom_get_ph1()`.

Comment: I thought of adding that to the answer, but then couldn't think of a how to do that... I'll update the answer.

Comment: I suppose this should work.

Comment: Thank you, guys, to make it even better, but the initial answer is exactly what I need, because there are several different pages using arguments from URL and each using its own themeing. And I need to pull them from another module and put into my custom module's output.